# Express-Router Library Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, express-router

I am using the Express.Router class to create modular route handlers. When I go to define the route:
`router.post('/dashboard/seo/update', checkAuth, dashboardController.updateSeo);` I get an error: `Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]`

Upon Logging output it turns out that the `checkAuth`  variable in the routes file is being set as an object and not a function. With my limited knowledge of JavaScript I am pretty sure that I am exporting checkAuth as a function using module.exports = checkAuth but I don't know why I am getting this error. For context this is my checkAuth function:

```
const admin = require('../Firebase/firebaseConfig');

// Middleware for checking if user is logged in
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    let loggedIn = false;
    // Check if the cookies exist and if the loggedIn cookie is set.
    if (req.cookies && req.cookies.developerIn) {
        // If it is, set loggedIn to true.
        loggedIn = true;
        // Verify the session cookie
        admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(req.cookies.developerIn, true)
            .then((decodedClaims) => {
                // Add the user's UID to the request object
                req.uid = decodedClaims.uid;
                // Continue to the next middleware function
                next();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // If the session cookie is invalid, redirect to the login page
                console.error('Failed to verify session cookie:', error);
                res.status(401).redirect('/login');
            });
    } else {
        // If the cookies don't exist or the loggedIn cookie isn't set, redirect to the login page
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}

module.exports = checkAuth;
```

And my routes file where I am initializing the checkAuth object:

```
const router = express.Router();

const dashboardController = require('../controllers/dashboardController');

const checkAuth = require('../middleware/authmiddleware');

//Check if dashboardController.updateSeo is a function
console.log("Dashoard controller is a: ", typeof dashboardController.updateSeo);
console.log("Checkauth is a: ", typeof checkAuth); //Returns an object

router.post('/dashboard/seo/update', checkAuth, dashboardController.updateSeo);

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried to clear the required cache before importing the checkAuth function like this:

```
`delete require.cache[require.resolve('../middleware/authmiddleware')];
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/authmiddleware'); `
```

This does not solve the issue either.
Any possible reasons that even with correct syntax, this error still persists? Am I missing something altogether?